# Segmentation Fault in Check Sum function C

Tags: c

when I try to do a test of my checksum function, I keep getting a segmentation fault.

```
int cksum(int *buf, int count) {
    long sum = 0;
    //if(count%2 == 1) { //if we are passing an odd number of bytes
    //  buf = strncat (*buf, '\0', 1);
    //} 
    while (count) {
        sum += *buf++;
        if (sum & 0xFFFF0000) { /* carry occurred, so wrap around */
            sum &= 0xFFFF;
            sum++;
        }
        count--;
    }
    return  ~(sum & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Testing the function:

```
char poo[6] = {'c', 'b', '1', '3' , '4', 'a'}; 
int my_check_value = cksum(poo, 6);
```

I get the error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I really am not sure where in the function I'm going wrong as I implemented it very simply. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't give a bus error instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the difference in size between an `int` and a `char`.

You're passing into the function a chunk of memory that is 6 bytes in size as each char is just 1 byte. But the function is expecting memory to be grouped into `int` which are 4 bytes and you're telling the function that there are 6 of them which means a total of 24 bytes.

How you want to proceed is up to you, but it seems logical that your function in it's current usage should take a `char *` instead of an `int *`?

Answer (score 1):

`int cksum(int *buf, int count)` is taking a pointer to `int` as a parameter. The call

```
int my_check_value = cksum(poo, 6);
```

is passing the `char` array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `char poo[6]` as an `int *buf` this is screwing all of your pointer arithmetic.  Either change poo to an int, or specify buf as a char *